# Do you uniquely id all of your models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js. I get an event from the server that needs to update a particular instance of a model in a collection of models.

Should I set the id attribute to achieve this, how do I target a model by its id?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, every model should have a unique id.

when you get the update from the server, find the model via the `get` method on the collection.

as a very simple example:

```
function receiveSomeUpdate(id, data){
  var model = myCollection.get(id);
  model.set(data);
}
```

do you have a specific scenario you're trying to support, tho? the details may change the answer